# How to get Map object in react-leaflet on zoom change event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet for showing non-geographical map. 
I also added some event for zoom changing. (**`onZoomEnd()`**)

I wonder how to access map object or map component and get current zoom level. Or other maps props?

```
  <Map
                center={this.getCalculatedCenterFromState()}
                zoom={this.getCalculatedZoomFromState()}
                minZoom={this.getCalculatedMinZoomFromState()}
                maxZoom={2}
                onZoomEnd={this.mapService.handleZoomstart(/* map.object */)}


               >
</Map
```

I need to access map object in handler method

```
handleZoomstart = (map) => {
        // TODO handle move event
    };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the map:

```
<Map
  ref={(ref) => { this.map = ref; }}
  {...}
>
(...)
</Map>
```

Then you can access the map:

```
handleZoomstart = (map) => {
  console.log(this.map && this.map.leafletElement);
};
```

And the current zoom:

```
getMapZoom() {
   return this.map && this.map.leafletElement.getZoom();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to pass map object to map event, but map is undefined before componentDidMount. And the event is set on map init. I maybe not understand what you want to suggest. I am also using handler from service and I must send parameter to the method.

Comment: You can't get the map object before componentDidMount because the Map isn't mount before. Why do you want to access the zoomStartEvent before mount?

Comment: Hm ok. I found where is the error. My handler method was in service and it was not able to see the state from Map Component.

Comment: Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 5):

Solutions under didn't work for me. If you use react-leaflet v3 you can use this.
One note, hook useMapEvents you need call from children component "MapContainer" it's impotant!

```
import {useMapEvents} from "react-leaflet";
import {useState} from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(5); // initial zoom level provided for MapContainer
    
    const mapEvents = useMapEvents({
        zoomend: () => {
            setZoomLevel(mapEvents.getZoom());
        },
    });

    console.log(zoomLevel);

    return null
}

function MyMapComponent() {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={5}>
            <MyComponent />
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be alternatively done without using refs. Use the event 'onZoomEnd'.

This event object has '_zoom' property, which is current zoom state.

`e.target._zoom`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the above problem quite simply. React leaflet provides a nice "onViewportChange" callback that captures center and zoom changes when using the map.

You need three things, the declared "Viewport" object, a function that supports callback 
and callback.

```
const viewport = {
center: [49.32707, 19.10041],
zoom: 5,
};

const onViewportChanged = (viewport) => {
console.log(viewport);
};

return (

<Map viewport={viewport} onViewportChanged={onViewportChanged}></Map>)
```

Best regards

Comment: This didn't work for me. It looks like `onViewportChange`/`onViewportChanged` no longer exist in React-Leaflet 3, which now has `MapContainer` as the top-level component.